# Is there a way to simplify this code in python and remove the step of converting the Excel sheet into a csv file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to extract all of the email addresses from an excel sheet to use to send an email to a group of people. the only way I've been able to do that so far is by converting to a csv file first. The excel sheet is not always the same and the format could change there are multiple columns with email addresses and some spots that are empty. Are there any solutions for this?

```
    #importing libraries
import pandas as pd
import csv
import re
  
# Read and store content of an excel file 
read_file = pd.read_excel ("Email_List.xlsx")
  
# Write the dataframe object into csv file
read_file.to_csv ("Test.csv",  index = None, header=True)
    
# Read the csv file contenets
with open('Test.csv') as csv_file:
    csv=csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    # join csv data into string
    for row in csv:
        data=(', '.join(row))

        # search for email addresses
        emails = re.findall("([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.,]+)", data)

        # print list of email addresses
        for mail in emails:
            print(mail)
```

Comment: do you have a sample excel file, for testing purposes?

Comment: but... you already read it as excel... why do you convert it to csv and then use `csv` module if you can already us it as a `DataFrame`? this looks confusing, like `read_file` is a `pandas.DataFrame`, why can't you iterate over that?

Comment: I would like to do that but I never came across a method of searching an entire excel sheet for email addresses

Comment: do the same thing you do with `csv`, iterate over every row in the dataframe, join them together and search for that email regex, maybe dataframe already has some find functions that support regex and could search the entire dataframe

Comment: If you are happy with the pandas import, then you can just spit the data frame out to a list of records and deal with those.  no need to save another file

Answer (score 1):

```
emails = (pd.read_excel("Email_List.xlsx", header=None).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
          .str.findall(pat=r"([\w_+\-]+@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-,]+)").explode())
print(emails)
```

Result:

```
0         first@email.aaa
0    second@email.example
1                   a@b.c
2     xxxx123@yyyy786.com
3        777aaa@fffff.org
dtype: object
```

Excel source:
[image]